# How to fix error "Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of" in angular unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have around 50 test cases written in Angular. On executing those it says `Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of 10000ms`. I did some configuration settings like

```
captureTimeout: 60000, // it was already there
browserDisconnectTimeout : 10000,
browserDisconnectTolerance : 1,
browserNoActivityTimeout : 60000,//by default 10000
```

Nothing seems to be working. If I extend the `browserDisconnectTimeout` time to `100000ms`, then its working fine, but upon adding more test cases it again throws the timeout error.

Comment: I would make sure query is good by running in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  The query may take a long time to run which you can check the run time in SSMS.

Comment: @jdweng it’s not about query there is no database hit for test cases

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484124/karma-disconnectedreconnect-failed-before-timeout-of-with-chromeheadless

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing asynchronous behaviour without promises resolving? This seems likely to me since you're only getting the error when running more tests.

Comment: Its done, thanks for the response though :)