# Karma: "Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of" with ChromeHeadless

Tags: karma-runner

In my AngularJS, npm times out when running tests, with message "Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of Xs" .
My karma.conf.js file is configured as such:

```
...
browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
...
```

Increasing these values didn't help - the same error would appear after the newly specified amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding this to my karma.conf.js file, below the browserNoActivityTimeout property.

```
flags: [
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--no-sandbox'
]
```

From https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/:

- disable-gpu flag disables GPU hardware acceleration
- no-sandbox disables the sandbox for all process that are normally sandboxed.

I had to use both of these in combination to eradicate the timeout in my project.