# Karma test fails to connect to launched 'chrome' instance

Tags: angular, npm, karma-jasmine

I have a Karma test running on a nodejs jenkins pod, npm times out to connect to the Chrome instance (on selenium hub).
Until yesterday this was working fine, there were no changes done to any of the configuration files, so I suspect an underlying infrastructure connectivity failure.
Note that the tests run absolutely fine locally, using my local Chrome instance.
My configuration looks like:

```
browsers: ['RemoteChrome'],
singleRun: true,
autoWatch: false,
hostname: getIpAddress('eth0', 'IPv4'), // On Kubernetes, the container's network is on eth0
port: getRandomPort(), // Random port is enough for now
browserNoActivityTimeout: 600000,
browserDisconnectTolerance: 5,
customLaunchers: {
    'RemoteChrome': {
        base: 'WebDriver',
        config: {
            hostname: 'selenium-hub.MY_COMPANY_DOMAIN.com',
            port: 80,
        },
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
}
```

The logs for a **successful** build look like this I get is:

```
15:43:47  + ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false
15:43:48  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
15:44:01  [32m10 01 2022 14:44:00.811:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:51500/
15:44:01  [32m10 01 2022 14:44:00.813:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers RemoteChrome with concurrency unlimited
15:44:01  [32m10 01 2022 14:44:00.820:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser chrome via Remote WebDriver
15:44:16  [32m10 01 2022 14:44:14.936:INFO [Chrome 94.0.4606 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket R0gwZjv8YroZjqsvAAAA with id 69976747
15:44:16  [33m10 01 2022 14:44:14.943:WARN [middleware:karma]: [39mInvalid file type (ts), defaulting to js.
15:44:24  Chrome 94.0.4606 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 402 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
```

But since the build started to **fail** I now get:

```
17:23:57  + ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false
17:23:59  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
17:24:11  [32m10 01 2022 16:24:11.124:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:46286/
17:24:11  [32m10 01 2022 16:24:11.125:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers RemoteChrome with concurrency unlimited
17:24:11  [32m10 01 2022 16:24:11.128:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser chrome via Remote WebDriver
17:24:26  [32m10 01 2022 16:24:25.472:INFO [Chrome 94.0.4606 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mConnected on socket Ml6Xc9tjNamow3MKAAAA with id 46407971
17:24:26  [33m10 01 2022 16:24:25.480:WARN [middleware:karma]: [39mInvalid file type (ts), defaulting to js.
17:24:58  [33m10 01 2022 16:24:57.466:WARN [Chrome 94.0.4606 (Linux 0.0.0)]: [39mDisconnected (0 times)reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (ping timeout)
17:24:58  Chrome 94.0.4606 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
17:24:58    Disconnectedreconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (ping timeout)
```

I have tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484124/karma-disconnectedreconnect-failed-before-timeout-of-with-chromeheadless) but it does not work.
Note that my selenium hub runs just fine, I can ping it and display its hub output on the browser.
Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: I saw your question on my question. But my question was deleted. I was having this problem and I found out that there were some tests that need user input to continue. (like printing)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it was indeed because of a connectivity problem....
 I had manually deleted the selenium-hub pod and the kubernetes Deployment recreated a pod which apparently did not connect well to its Service.
Anyways, after redeploying all components (Deployment, Service and Ingress) everything got back in synch again and the issue disappeared.